# failure - test failed: the network adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed oracle 11g in my machine and created tablespaces and user.
Evereything ran succesfully. Now im trying to create a new conenction thru sqlDeveloper but i get this error. I checked the SID name and changed them according to tnsnames.ora. what else might go wrong?

Comment: Is the DB daemon running ? Is the hostname correct ? Tried replacing it with just IP address ? Are the port and username correct ? What operating system you use ?

Comment: yes i replaced with IP. Port and user names are correct.Mine is windows & professional. even after replacing with my IP i get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the tnsnames.ora and set the connection type to "Basic".
Enter your connection details (SID, Port, host, username and password) accordingly.

Comment: My connection type is basic. rest of the credentials looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use connection type basic, and dont use hyphen "-" in the connection name, while use underscore "_". and then try again to connect

Answer (score 0):

If the database is on your machine, and you're still talking about 11g, then you can simply do this:

[image]

Connection Type: Basic
Hostname: localhost (you said it the db was on YOUR machine, yes?)
Port: 1521 (this is the default unless you changed it)
SID: orcl for regular db or xe for Express edition
Service Name: use this if 12c with Pluggable Database

Or course for username and password:
 username: system (a default ADMIN account, less dangerous than SYS)
 password: whatever you provided when creating your database

If you are going to login as SYS, you must change the Role from default to SYSDBA.

If you have TNSNames.ora file, we should find it, and you can set your Connection Type to TNS, and simply pick your database from the dropdown.

[image]

As you can imagine, when you have MANY databases, the TNS path is much easier, but you will need to maintain this file. Otherwise, Basic is the easiest way to go.